# c# web browser instagram not working

Tags: c#, browser, instagram, bots

I am developing a program for instagram that will connect to the website(INSTAGRAM.COM). I've done many times so far. In this way the first time, but I'm having a problem with.

I would like to automatically log the user name and password
but cant see code behind username control https://instagram.com/accounts/login/

here i want click follow button but came across the following code.

What can I do. How do I view. How can I do the same again. as in the example.
***webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("send").InvokeMember("click");***

***I've tried many times but did not. profile page code does not in any way.***

***From LOGIN;***

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://instagram.com/test");
 while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
```

***RESULT no control on the page you can see the unreachable;***

```
textBox1.Text = webBrowser1.DocumentText;

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="tr" class="hl-tr logged-in 


">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>
Instagram
</title>

    <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex" />

    <link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/x-icon" href="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/669b453/images/ico/favicon.ico" />

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/669b453/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/669b453/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/669b453/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/669b453/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png" />


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />




    <script type="text/javascript">
        GATEKEEPERS = {
            banzai_logs: true
        };
    </script>


        <script src="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/669b453/scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/669b453/scripts/bluebar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>





<meta property="og:type" content="profile" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_44291_75sq_1360259321.jpg" />
<meta property="og:title" content="test on Instagram" />
<meta property="og:description" content="bristol" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://instagram.com/test" />






</head>
<body class="">













        <script type="text/javascript">
window._strings = {

"%(count)s comments": "%(count)s comments",
"%(count)s followers": "%(count)s followers",
"%(count)s following": "%(count)s following",
"%(count)s likes": "%(count)s likes",
"%(count)s more comments": "%(count)s more comments",
"%(count)s new posts": "%(count)s new posts",
"%(count)s people liked this photo": "%(count)s people liked this photo",
"%(count)s photos,": "%(count)s photos,",
"%(count)s posts": "%(count)s posts",
"%(count)s+ new posts": "%(count)s+ new posts",
"%(day)s %(month_name)s %(year)s": "%(day)s %(month_name)s %(year)s",
"%(days)s days ago": "%(days)s gün önce",
"%(days)sd": "%(days)sg",
"%(followerCount)s followers": "%(followerCount)s followers",
"%(hours)s hours ago": "%(hours)s saat önce",
"%(hours)sh": "%(hours)ss",
"%(likes)s likes, %(comments)s comments": "%(likes)s likes, %(comments)s comments",
"%(mediaCount)s photos": "%(mediaCount)s photos",
"%(minutes)s minutes ago": "%(minutes)s dakika önce",
"%(minutes)sm": "%(minutes)sd",
"%(months)s months ago": "%(months)s ay önce",
"%(seconds)s seconds ago": "%(seconds)s saniye önce",
"%(seconds)ss": "%(seconds)ssn",
"%(user)s on Instagram": "%(user)s on Instagram",
"%(username)s on Instagram": "%(username)s on Instagram",
"%(weeks)s weeks ago": "%(weeks)s hafta önce",
"%(weeks)sw": "%(weeks)sh",
"%(year)s %(month)s": "%(year)s %(month)s",
"1": "1",
"1 comment": "1 comment",
"1 day ago": "1 gün önce",
"1 follower": "1 follower",
"1 hour ago": "1 saat önce",
"1 like": "1 like",
"1 minute ago": "1 dakika önce",
"1 month ago": "1 ay önce",
"1 more comment": "1 more comment",
"1 new post": "1 new post",
"1 photo>": "1 photo\u003E",
"1 second ago": "1 saniye önce",
"1 week ago": "1 hafta önce",
"2": "2",
"3": "3",
"AM": "AM",
"About us": "Hakkımızda",
"Account Insights - Instagram": "Account Insights \u002D Instagram",
"Add a caption...": "Add a caption...",
"Add a comment": "Add a comment",
"All items loaded": "All items loaded",
"Apr": "Apr",
"April": "Nisan",
"Are you sure you want to delete this comment?": "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?",
"Are you sure?": "Are you sure?",
"Audience": "Audience",
"Aug": "Aug",
"August": "Ağustos",
"Badges": "Kartlar",
"Blog": "Blog",
"By using this embed, you agree to Instagram\\'s <a href=\"http://instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/\">API Terms of Use</a>.": "By using this embed, you agree to Instagram\u005C\u0027s \u003Ca href\u003D\u0022http://instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/\u0022\u003EAPI Terms of Use\u003C/a\u003E.",
"Cancel": "İptal",
"Content unavailable": "Content unavailable",
"Copy Embed Code": "Copy Embed Code",
"Copy this code:": "Copy this code:",
"Couldn\\'t post comment": "Couldn\u005C\u0027t post comment",
"Dec": "Dec",
"December": "Aralık",
"Delete": "Sil",
"Edit Profile": "Profili Düzenle",
"Embed": "Embed",
"Feb": "Feb",
"February": "Şubat",
"Follow": "Takip Et",
"Follow %(username)s on Instagram": "Follow %(username)s on Instagram",
"Follow friends and interesting people to see their photos here.": "Follow friends and interesting people to see their photos here.",
"Following": "Takip Ediyorsun",
"Forgot your password?": "Forgot your password?",
"Fri": "Fri",
"Friday": "Friday",
"Here are some suggestions.": "Here are some suggestions.",
"Home": "Ana Sayfa",
"Jan": "Jan",
"January": "Ocak",
"Jobs": "İş Fırsatları",
"Jul": "Jul",
"July": "Temmuz",
"Jun": "Jun",
"June": "Haziran",
"Leave a comment...": "Leave a comment...",
"Like": "Beğen",
"Likes": "Beğendiklerin",
"Load More...": "Load More...",
"Load more": "Load more",
"Load more...": "Load more...",
"Loading more...": "Loading more...",
"Loading...": "Loading...",
"Log Out": "Çıkış Yap",
"Log in": "giriş yap",
"Mar": "Mar",
"March": "Mart",
"May": "Mayıs",
"Mon": "Mon",
"Monday": "Monday",
"More": "More",
"Next photo": "Next photo",
"No Recent Photos": "No Recent Photos",
"No likes yet.": "Henüz beğenen yok.",
"No photos to show.": "No photos to show.",
"Nov": "Nov",
"November": "Kasım",
"Now": "Now",
"Oct": "Oct",
"October": "Ekim",
"Open in App": "Uygulamada aç",
"Others": "Others",
"PM": "PM",
"Password:": "Password:",
"Paste it on your website, blog, or wherever you want to link to your profile!": "Paste it on your website, blog, or wherever you want to link to your profile!",
"People you follow": "People you follow",
"Performance": "Performance",
"Photo by %(username)s": "Fotoğraf: %(username)s",
"Posts": "Posts",
"Press": "Basın",
"Press Page - Instagram": "Press Page \u002D Instagram",
"Previous Posts": "Previous Posts",
"Previous photo": "Previous photo",
"Privacy": "Gizlilik",
"Report inappropriate": "Report inappropriate",
"Requested": "İstek Gönderildi",
"Retry": "Retry",
"Sat": "Sat",
"Saturday": "Saturday",
"Select your badge:": "Select your badge:",
"Sep": "Sep",
"September": "Eylül",
"Summary": "Summary",
"Sun": "Sun",
"Sunday": "Sunday",
"Support": "Destek",
"Terms": "Koşullar",
"This user is private": "Bu kullanıcının profili gizli",
"Thu": "Thu",
"Thursday": "Thursday",
"To follow %(username)s, you need to log in.": "To follow %(username)s, you need to log in.",
"Toggle like": "Toggle like",
"Tue": "Tue",
"Tuesday": "Tuesday",
"Username:": "Username:",
"Video by %(username)s": "Video by %(username)s",
"View Photo Page": "View Photo Page",
"View Profile": "Profil",
"View Video Page": "View Video Page",
"View on Instagram": "View on Instagram",
"Wed": "Wed",
"Wednesday": "Wednesday",
"When you are finished following people,": "When you are finished following people,",
"Write a comment...": "Write a comment...",
"Yes": "Evet",
"You must log in to add a comment.": "You must log in to add a comment.",
"You must log in to like this photo.": "You must log in to like this photo.",
"You need to be following %(username)s to like or comment": "Beğenmek veya yorum yapmak için %(username)s\u0027i takip etmen gerekiyor",
"Your username or password was incorrect.": "Your username or password was incorrect.",
"am": "am",
"banner photo": "banner photo",
"nd": "nd",
"pm": "pm",
"rd": "rd",
"reload this page": "reload this page",
"st": "st",
"th": "th"
};
</script>

<script src=//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/669b453/scripts/polyfills/es5-shim.min.js></script>
<script src=//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/669b453/scripts/polyfills/es5-sham.min.js></script>
<script src=//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/669b453/scripts/polyfills/history.js/scripts/bundled/html5/native.history.js></script>


<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"static_root":"\/\/d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net\/bluebar\/669b453","platform":{"is_touch":false,"app_platform":"web"},"hostname":"instagram.com","entry_data":{"UserProfile":[{"canSeePrerelease":false,"relationship":{"incoming_request":false,"followed_by":false,"outgoing_request":false,"following":false,"blocking":false,"is_private":false},"viewer":{"username":"tarzdunyasicom","website":"http:\/\/www.tarzdunyasi.com","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-b.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10727618_368981779931057_1206278300_a.jpg","bio":"info@tarzdunyasi.com | kredi kart\u0131 ge\u00e7erlidir.","is_advertiser":false,"is_staff":false,"full_name":"Tarz D\u00fcnyas\u0131","id":"1531622615"},"countryBlockInfo":null,"__get_params":{},"staticRoot":"\/\/d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net\/bluebar\/669b453","userMedia":[{"can_delete_comments":false,"location":null,"type":"image","can_view_comments":true,"comments":{"count":0,"data":[]},"alt_media_url":"http:\/\/distilleryvesper0-8.ak.instagram.com\/acf3a29445e811e4a90ef45214c94968_101.mp4","caption":{"created_time":"1411782664","text":"murlo","from":{"username":"test","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_44291_75sq_1360259321.jpg","id":"44291","full_name":"julian"},"id":"818414766065390579"},"link":"http:\/\/instagram.com\/p\/tbl-SlwxLq\/","likes":{"count":10,"data":[{"username":"_ailuufernandez_","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-f.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10693519_286336701574277_1873916209_a.jpg","id":"861945611","full_name":"Ailuu \u2661"},{"username":"lailyrichards","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_271195814_75sq_1371302283.jpg","id":"271195814","full_name":"Laily Richards"},{"username":"frksyre","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-a.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xpa1\/924583_520833911380624_937642656_a.jpg","id":"1322409958","full_name":"yzma"},{"username":"adfgboab","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/anonymousUser.jpg","id":"1510935583","full_name":"adfgboab"}]},"created_time":"1411782664","images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"http:\/\/scontent-b-fra.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xaf1\/t51.2885-15\/10665475_1547163765498281_1479296847_a.jpg","width":306,"height":306},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/scontent-b-fra.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xaf1\/t51.2885-15\/10665475_1547163765498281_1479296847_s.jpg","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"http:\/\/scontent-b-fra.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xaf1\/t51.2885-15\/10665475_1547163765498281_1479296847_n.jpg","width":640,"height":640}},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"818414765587239658_44291","user":{"username":"test","website":"","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_44291_75sq_1360259321.jpg","full_name":"julian","bio":"","id":"44291"}},{"can_delete_comments":false,"location":null,"type":"image","can_view_comments":true,"comments":{"count":19,"data":[{"created_time":"1403880498","text":"Nice","from":{"username":"wpac_007","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/anonymousUser.jpg","id":"1252264779","full_name":"wpac_007"},"id":"752126589768241200"},{"created_time":"1404029057","text":"test","from":{"username":"rowan.quintero","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-c.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10706879_553060301493042_1613126282_a.jpg","id":"1135158196","full_name":"Rowan Quintero"},"id":"753372792086532926"},{"created_time":"1404158130","text":"Est","from":{"username":"kingap15","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-d.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xap1\/10472042_478059898963283_2115367155_a.jpg","id":"1279704899","full_name":"kermaperse"},"id":"754455539785863623"},{"created_time":"1404502042","text":"#hashtag","from":{"username":"maraduck","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-g.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10666237_1467547046838966_374103407_a.jpg","id":"316785026","full_name":"Don't forget to smile\ud83d\ude0a"},"id":"757340483411448629"},{"created_time":"1404918143","text":"gay","from":{"username":"asus_damian","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/anonymousUser.jpg","id":"646283208","full_name":"D A M I A N____W E B E R"},"id":"760830988183080981"},{"created_time":"1404922253","text":"much gay such rainbow","from":{"username":"frksyre","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-a.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xpa1\/924583_520833911380624_937642656_a.jpg","id":"1322409958","full_name":"yzma"},"id":"760865468440580256"},{"created_time":"1404924666","text":"hahaha","from":{"username":"test","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_44291_75sq_1360259321.jpg","id":"44291","full_name":"julian"},"id":"760885708205527489"},{"created_time":"1405004254","text":"Make","from":{"username":"mattgales__","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-f.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10727333_302623859924517_1805048324_a.jpg","id":"299135431","full_name":"Matthew"},"id":"761553340546093537"},{"created_time":"1405004256","text":"Jake","from":{"username":"mattgales__","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-f.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10727333_302623859924517_1805048324_a.jpg","id":"299135431","full_name":"Matthew"},"id":"761553355947577827"},{"created_time":"1405004257","text":"Lame","from":{"username":"mattgales__","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-f.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10727333_302623859924517_1805048324_a.jpg","id":"299135431","full_name":"Matthew"},"id":"761553369981719014"},{"created_time":"1405004259","text":"Leaks","from":{"username":"mattgales__","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-f.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10727333_302623859924517_1805048324_a.jpg","id":"299135431","full_name":"Matthew"},"id":"761553383143444969"},{"created_time":"1405101509","text":".\u0e38blah","from":{"username":"jadonisajadawg","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-g.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10643939_699960146735838_2095543155_a.jpg","id":"836402786","full_name":"Jadon Allen"},"id":"762369178048074035"},{"created_time":"1405856088","text":"Connard","from":{"username":"joe_lagaffe","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-h.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10608063_690444624363983_106414853_a.jpg","id":"1321723270","full_name":"Jonathan Burla"},"id":"768699042313212769"},{"created_time":"1406304734","text":"super!","from":{"username":"jimbojonez84","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/anonymousUser.jpg","id":"1367152449","full_name":"jimbojonez84"},"id":"772462555766657503"},{"created_time":"1408190142","text":"Would you to sell your account ?","from":{"username":"instaarabcom","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_194734932_75sq_1383696056.jpg","id":"194734932","full_name":"\u0627\u0639\u0644\u0627\u0646\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0646\u0633\u062a\u0642\u0631\u0627\u0645"},"id":"788278504012845311"},{"created_time":"1409147785","text":"I DONT WANT TO TAKE A TEST\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude2d","from":{"username":"gxbya","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-h.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10723818_535357976598119_2064117608_a.jpg","id":"801538995","full_name":"gaby\u30c4"},"id":"796311802664390843"},{"created_time":"1411301225","text":"@test can I have your account for 3 mega shoutouts","from":{"username":"toppsian","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-a.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10693259_871224056223144_1534322169_a.jpg","id":"330795789","full_name":"Bunt Username - Caribbean"},"id":"814376163672790014"}]},"alt_media_url":"http:\/\/distilleryvesper10-6.ak.instagram.com\/60549aa8daac11e3864b0002c9543af6_101.mp4","caption":null,"link":"http:\/\/instagram.com\/p\/n8NAzkwxGa\/","likes":{"count":96,"data":[{"username":"elnjouly","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-a.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10616931_299386003580440_962563054_a.jpg","id":"680304000","full_name":"\u010ch\u00e8\u0164\u00f4\u0161"},{"username":"___.___._","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-b.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10546582_778724302147945_955047836_a.jpg","id":"215613241","full_name":"\ufeff\u2003\ufeff\u2003\ufeff\u2003\ufeff\u2003\ufeff \u2003 \u24d0\u24e8\u24dc\u24d0\u24dd \u24d2\u24d0\u24dc\u24df\u24d1\u24d4\u24db\u24db"},{"username":"lukajane","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-g.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10727797_401345276687566_1512940636_a.jpg","id":"8477045","full_name":"\ud83c\udf88 luka \ud83d\udc80"},{"username":"prismetrictech","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/anonymousUser.jpg","id":"1427504511","full_name":"pris"}]},"created_time":"1399991972","images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"http:\/\/scontent-b-fra.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xfp1\/t51.2885-15\/10375671_661014213951831_952072032_a.jpg","width":306,"height":306},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/scontent-b-fra.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xfp1\/t51.2885-15\/10375671_661014213951831_952072032_s.jpg","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"http:\/\/scontent-b-fra.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xfp1\/t51.2885-15\/10375671_661014213951831_952072032_n.jpg","width":640,"height":640}},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"719507270454677914_44291","user":{"username":"test","website":"","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_44291_75sq_1360259321.jpg","full_name":"julian","bio":"","id":"44291"}},{"can_delete_comments":false,"location":null,"type":"image","can_view_comments":true,"comments":{"count":32,"data":[{"created_time":"1390313493","text":"@ganeshrv","from":{"username":"ganeshrv","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_325959766_75sq_1363142982.jpg","id":"325959766","full_name":"ganesh venkat rao"},"id":"638318306729857033"},{"created_time":"1390517405","text":"Hahaha @igbots rejected!","from":{"username":"lol_jalove_piecakes","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_990405013_75sq_1389994058.jpg","id":"990405013","full_name":"Sugar Pete"},"id":"640028842911797442"},{"created_time":"1391404342","text":"Randomness @test  that's amazing lol in how random you can be haha @test","from":{"username":"1mp3rfection","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-a.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10616789_283586085183144_1640686046_a.jpg","id":"411401184","full_name":"09\/03\/14"},"id":"647469010572742974"},{"created_time":"1394112416","text":"The purge... That movie is creepy.","from":{"username":"freddyyvincent","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-e.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/1208200_1562040237364308_22878542_a.jpg","id":"362290361","full_name":"Fred Vincent"},"id":"670185983127524333"},{"created_time":"1395511358","text":":D @test","from":{"username":"asdtiiaasd","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_1195852079_75sq_1395477029.jpg","id":"1195852079","full_name":"Tiia"},"id":"681921157401875080"},{"created_time":"1397506633","text":"Test","from":{"username":"pouryam","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_15142038_75sq_1345172295.jpg","id":"15142038","full_name":"Pourya M"},"id":"698658740987171399"},{"created_time":"1397740035","text":"Der test","from":{"username":"alena_horan_1","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-d.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10723804_629196087197899_2122300680_a.jpg","id":"553503444","full_name":"\u00bbOneDirection\u00ab"},"id":"700616653192499784"},{"created_time":"1398384401","text":"@test","from":{"username":"willburg98","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_965434191_75sq_1393699681.jpg","id":"965434191","full_name":"Will Burgoyne"},"id":"706021992587005976"},{"created_time":"1399181074","text":"Test","from":{"username":"quinten_schooler","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-f.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10665473_968714816477181_1525276106_a.jpg","id":"562855514","full_name":"Like A Boss\ud83d\ude0e"},"id":"712704965977772189"},{"created_time":"1399603239","text":"Test test test","from":{"username":"nicky2877","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_1104813384_75sq_1392760664.jpg","id":"1104813384","full_name":"Nicky De Klerk"},"id":"716246344343425747"},{"created_time":"1403419378","text":"#\u003c--hashtag","from":{"username":"taco_duck_","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-d.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xpa1\/928559_757205687657675_79361102_a.jpg","id":"1368425205","full_name":"Hayden Sweeny"},"id":"748258441725940668"},{"created_time":"1403419406","text":"# \u003c---- hashtag","from":{"username":"taco_duck_","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-d.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xpa1\/928559_757205687657675_79361102_a.jpg","id":"1368425205","full_name":"Hayden Sweeny"},"id":"748258676304974791"},{"created_time":"1404034010","text":"go","from":{"username":"rowan.quintero","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-c.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10706879_553060301493042_1613126282_a.jpg","id":"1135158196","full_name":"Rowan Quintero"},"id":"753414341658874051"},{"created_time":"1404158117","text":"Testis es","from":{"username":"kingap15","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-d.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xap1\/10472042_478059898963283_2115367155_a.jpg","id":"1279704899","full_name":"kermaperse"},"id":"754455430507467200"},{"created_time":"1405856094","text":"Pd","from":{"username":"joe_lagaffe","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-h.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10608063_690444624363983_106414853_a.jpg","id":"1321723270","full_name":"Jonathan Burla"},"id":"768699096621060963"},{"created_time":"1405931662","text":"#","from":{"username":"maraduck","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-g.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10666237_1467547046838966_374103407_a.jpg","id":"316785026","full_name":"Don't forget to smile\ud83d\ude0a"},"id":"769333001497809460"},{"created_time":"1405931677","text":"##","from":{"username":"maraduck","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-g.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10666237_1467547046838966_374103407_a.jpg","id":"316785026","full_name":"Don't forget to smile\ud83d\ude0a"},"id":"769333130615263801"},{"created_time":"1405931680","text":"###","from":{"username":"maraduck","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-g.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10666237_1467547046838966_374103407_a.jpg","id":"316785026","full_name":"Don't forget to smile\ud83d\ude0a"},"id":"769333153834930747"},{"created_time":"1409990815","text":"Wtf at the comments lol","from":{"username":"lukajane","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-g.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10727797_401345276687566_1512940636_a.jpg","id":"8477045","full_name":"\ud83c\udf88 luka \ud83d\udc80"},"id":"803383643191054522"},{"created_time":"1410897422","text":"#benficazenit","from":{"username":"seligoroff","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-b.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10684343_702676703135481_1579260958_a.jpg","id":"290215878","full_name":"Igor Selivanov"},"id":"810988816583299373"}]},"alt_media_url":"http:\/\/distilleryvesper7-15.ak.instagram.com\/17cefb2c47ca11e382a90ad12b6d3376_101.mp4","caption":null,"link":"http:\/\/instagram.com\/p\/ga5NKuQxEP\/","likes":{"count":144,"data":[{"username":"elnjouly","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-a.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10616931_299386003580440_962563054_a.jpg","id":"680304000","full_name":"\u010ch\u00e8\u0164\u00f4\u0161"},{"username":"mademoisellexpatience","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-d.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10661037_346681275508867_591546949_a.jpg","id":"384658083","full_name":"Lui\ud83d\udc95"},{"username":"emilybchung","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-b.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10727460_467497190057369_1148111557_a.jpg","id":"181241021","full_name":"\u2605 7\/28\/13 \u262a"},{"username":"how_many_likez","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-b.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10561008_514633385335537_601603813_a.jpg","id":"1430954293","full_name":"how_many_likez"}]},"created_time":"1383841905","images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"http:\/\/scontent-a-fra.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xaf1\/t51.2885-15\/1171989_1377270952517966_892029388_a.jpg","width":306,"height":306},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/scontent-a-fra.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xaf1\/t51.2885-15\/1171989_1377270952517966_892029388_s.jpg","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"http:\/\/scontent-a-fra.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xaf1\/t51.2885-15\/1171989_1377270952517966_892029388_n.jpg","width":640,"height":640}},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"584030695215796495_44291","user":{"username":"test","website":"","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_44291_75sq_1360259321.jpg","full_name":"julian","bio":"","id":"44291"}}],"isAdvertiser":false,"__query_string":"?","onlyAds":false,"prerelease":false,"user":{"username":"test","bio":"bristol","website":"http:\/\/www.twitter.com\/9","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_44291_75sq_1360259321.jpg","full_name":"julian","counts":{"media":3,"followed_by":9289,"follows":68},"id":"44291"},"moreAvailable":false,"__path":"\/test\/","isStaff":false}]},"country_code":"TR","config":{"viewer":{"username":"tarzdunyasicom","website":"http:\/\/www.tarzdunyasi.com","profile_picture":"http:\/\/photos-b.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10727618_368981779931057_1206278300_a.jpg","bio":"info@tarzdunyasi.com | kredi kart\u0131 ge\u00e7erlidir.","is_advertiser":false,"is_staff":false,"full_name":"Tarz D\u00fcnyas\u0131","id":"1531622615"},"csrf_token":"97a560703b6449bcac68e82ac1ce5c63"}};</script>
<script src="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/669b453/cache/bundles/webpack-common.js"></script>
<script src="//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/669b453/cache/bundles/UserProfile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```